# Avoid element from hiding when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element on the page and would like to be visible at the bottom of the window when page is scrolled down and over the element. and when the page is scroll up it will back to the original position. Any suggestion with jquery and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basicaly have two choices afaik. `position:fixed;`, or having a `wrapper` around your page content, with `height: 100%;`  and `overflow: scroll;` then you set `position: relative;` to both elements and a larger `z-index` value for the element you want above your page.